# How to take sample from dask dataframe having all the products ordered by certain number of customers alone?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I tried loading my csv file using pd.read_csv. It has 33 million records and takes too much time for loading and querying also.

I have data of 200k customers.
This is the code I have written for sampling

Data is loading quickly when using a dask dataframe but takes much time for queries.

```
df_s = df.sample(frac = 300000/33819106,replace = None,random_state = 10)
```

This works fine but the customers have ordered many products. In the sample how to include all the products of the customers. How to sample based on customer id?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data into a dataframe and then sample from it. Output to a new .csv that is easier to read from.

```
df = pd.read_csv('customers.csv') 

df = df.sample(frac=.2) # 20% of the rows will be sampled. 

df.to_csv('sample_customers.csv')  # Create an easier to work with .csv
```

Generally the format of a question on here is

1. Description of problem
2. Desired outcome
3. What you've tried
4. Minimum reproducible example

Comment: Hello? did you abandon your question?

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory please accept it

Comment: yes actually I have edited the question. Can you give your suggestions on this